# How to pass multiple variable types to php using jQuery Ajax.Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to pass an array and a string to my php page.  But I cannot figure out how to do this.  Here is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
function processData(myVar){
  new Ajax.Request('myPage.php', {
    type: 'post',
    data: {myCmd: 'ProcessIt', addData: myVar},
      onSuccess: function(transport) {
        return transport.responseText;
      }
  });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST)){
 // $_POST is always empty.  Even though the type is array.
}
```

As my comment says, `$_POST` is always empty.  I have tried many ways to get some values out of it, but it is just empty.

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is `Ajax.Request`? I don't remember such stuff in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want send POST with prototypejs this is the form in ajax

```
new Ajax.Request('index/index.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  parameters: {
    'options[]': JSON.stringify({"array1" : "option1", "array2" : "option2"}),
   'option': "test"
  },
  onSuccess: function(transport){
    console.log(transport);
  }
});
```

I hope this help you

index.php

```
if(empty($_POST)){
  echo "BAD";
}else{
  echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ricardo!  That was a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a html form POST you can do this.

`<input type="text" name="nameOfInput[]">`

The `[]` means it POSTS as an array.

Comment: It's not an html form POST>